# Callback executed before function finishes execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hello I have this problem, whenever I execute this code the callback is executed before de main function finishes the execution. I believe it has something to do with async functions

```
var leers3 = async function (next) {
    var executed = [];
    AWS.config.update({
        region: '********',
        accessKeyId: '*********',
        secretAccessKey: '*********'
    });

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    s3.listObjects({Bucket:'*******'}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(fechaActual() + " Error: Error ejecutando cruce con S3.")
        }else{
            var files = [];
            data.Contents.forEach(function(obj,index){
                if(obj.Key.startsWith("*****") || obj.Key.startsWith("*****")){
                    files.push(obj.Key);
                }
            })
            files.forEach((file) => {
                var id_cajero = file.split('_')[1];
                var params = {Bucket:'*****', Key: file};
                var sql = "SELECT id_entidad FROM cajero WHERE id_cajero = '" + id_cajero + "';";
                dbConnection.query(sql, async(err,result) => {
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                    else{
                        var fileExecutedData = await leerarchivos3(params, s3, id_cajero, result[0].id_entidad);
                        fileExecutedData.file = file;
                        executed.push(fileExecutedData);
                        //console.log(executed);    
                    }
                })
                next(executed);                 
            })
        }
    })
};

leers3((executed) => {
        console.log(executed);
    });
```

Comment: which one is the callback and which one your main functions?

Comment: I am executing the funciont leers3 at the end of the page, and inside that I define a simple callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` is not designed to handle/execute promises & async code. `forEach` is designed to be a synchronous operation. This means that for each `file` you iterate over, where you think the execution is pausing, in fact, Javascript continues to the next iteration. You won't be able to guarantee the execution time of the `dbConnection.query` callbacks. If you use `Promise.all` with a little change up to `Array.map` you can achieve a  more predictable outcome & leverage the 'parallel' capabilities `Promise.all` gives. Here is pseudo-code inspired by your example.

```
    await Promise.all(
        files.map((file) => {
            const id_cajero = file.split("_")[1];
            const params = { Bucket: "*****", Key: file };
            const sql = `SELECT id_entidad FROM cajero WHERE id_cajero = '${id_cajero}';`;

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                dbConnection.query(sql, async (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }

                    const fileExecutedData = await leerarchivos3(
                        params,
                        s3,
                        id_cajero,
                        result[0].id_entidad
                    );

                    fileExecutedData.file = file;

                    executed.push(fileExecutedData);

                    return resolve();
                });
            });
        })
    );

    next(executed);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, it worked perfectly, Deifnitely I have to leanr a lot more about Promises. Again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend turning your `s3.listObjects` call into a promise.

```
const data = await s3.listObjects({Bucket:'*******'}).promise();
// ... do things with the data that is currently in your callback
```

I assume the `dbConnection.query` has an async/await (i.e. Promise) option as well.

If you must use callbacks then you should remove the `async` from the function.